# How can I move a validation into a common file and import it?

Tags: validation, nginx, virtualhost

I have multiple virtual hosts, managed by Nginx.

I received a ticket which asks me to validate the value of a request header for some virtual hosts and refuse serving requests if the header is absent or invalid. This is what I have added to each of the virtual hosts:

```
location / {
    if ($http_my_request_header_name != "<mytoken>") {
        return 406;
    }
}
```

And this is working as expected. However, I intend to make this solution more elegant and create a new config file, called common.conf, and, instead of pasting the same code into all virtual hosts, include this common file, as:

```
include conf.d/common.conf;
```

Yet, my tries were all failing:

## First attempt

Pasting the `if` conditional and leave the `location` directive in the virtual host, which would `include` the file. The error I received was telling me in the logs that I cannot have an `if` by itself in the file.

## Second attempt

I have moved the whole

```
location / {
    if ($http_my_request_header_name != "<mytoken>") {
        return 406;
    }
}
```

into the common file and replaced it with the `include` at the virtual host configs. The error I received was telling me that I need to wrap a `server` directive around the `location` directive.

## Third attempt

I have wrapped a server directive around my location directive, but that errored out as well. I no longer have the error, because I destroyed the server since then and recreated it. But if the exact error message is needed, let me know, I will reproduce it and share it here then.

## Question

How can I create a common config file that would validate for a request header and include it into multiple virtual host configs?

EDIT

In view of Rahul Sharma's answer, I'm providing further information of the current try. This is how the main conf looks alike currently:

```
server {
...
    include conf.d/common.conf;
...
}
```

and the `include` is a direct child of the `server` directive, that is, nothing else is wrapped around the `include. Earlier, instead of the` include` line, the main conf had its content, like

```
server {
...
    location / {
        if ($http_my_request_header_name != "<mytoken>") {
            return 406;
        }
    }
...
}
```

and it worked. I have literally moved the `location /` to the common.conf file and replaced it with the `include`. So, Nginx dislikes my other file for some reason. This is why it was strange to me and this is what led me to ask this question.

Comment: Your second attempt is the one which should be working. If you're getting the error, there's something else going on with the configurations. Please paste the exact error you're getting along with the contents of `nginx.conf` and `common.conf` files.

Comment: @RahulSharma tried the second attempt again, this is what I see in the error logs: `2022/10/05 16:00:31 [emerg] 1843#1843: "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/common.conf:1`. Basically it dislikes my common.conf having a `location` directive and presumably something is to be wrapped around it. But I have very limited knowledge of nginx's syntax and I do not know what's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that in nginx.conf there was a line of

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

which included common.conf at another place that I was not aware of and in that second place the code inside common.conf was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the contents of your `conf.d/common.conf` file is:

```
location / {
    if ($http_my_request_header_name != "<mytoken>") {
        return 406;
    }
}
```

The error

> "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/common.conf

is because probably your `include` statement inside the main `nginx.conf` is misplaced. The line `include conf.d/common.conf;` should be inside a `server` block for this to work like this:

```
server {
    ...
    ...
    include conf.d/common.conf;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem. I have edited my question with further information, showing that I have moved this code from the main conf and replaced it with the include and this is when this started to not work.

Comment: That's strange. Can you show the entire content of your `nginx.conf` file?

Comment: Unfortunately it's confidential. But, if there was a working example of delegating `location` into another file and including it into the conf, that would of course be a valid answer. So, if you choose to ignore my example and you point me to a proof-of-concept of this working, then it would be a valid answer. Your current answer is very logical, but solves a different problem from the one I have.